# How hide columns based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a solution to hide display specefic columns based on cell value.

For example: `When B2=Démission, then it shows only columns: J to O AND AE to AK`

```
When B2=Retraite, then it shows only columns: I AND P to W

When B2=Fin de mandat, then it shows only columns: H AND X to AD
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- From the following sample situation,

  > When B2=Démission, then it shows only columns: J to O AND AE to AK

  > When B2=Retraite, then it shows only columns: I AND P to W

  > When B2=Fin de mandat, then it shows only columns: H AND X to AD
- You want to achieve these situations using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the value to the cell "B2". And, run the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  
  // This condition is from your question.
  const obj = {
    "Démission": [{ "from": "J", "to": "O" }, { "from": "AE", "to": "AK" }],
    "Retraite": [{ "from": "I", "to": "I" }, { "from": "P", "to": "W" }],
    "Fin de mandat": [{ "from": "H", "to": "H" }, { "from": "X", "to": "AD" }],
  };

  const columnLetterToIndex_ = letter => [...letter.toUpperCase()].reduce((c, e, i, a) => (c += (e.charCodeAt(0) - 64) * Math.pow(26, a.length - i - 1)), -1);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const value = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  if (!obj[value]) return;
  sheet.showColumns(1, 1);
  sheet.hideColumns(2, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1);
  obj[value].forEach(({ from, to }) => {
    const start = columnLetterToIndex_(from) + 1;
    const end = columnLetterToIndex_(to) + 1;
    sheet.showColumns(start, from == to ? 1 : end - start + 1);
    if (start != 1) sheet.hideColumns(1);
  });
}
```

- When this sample script is run, for example, when the value of cell "B2" is `Démission`, the columns from "J" to "O" and from "AE" to "AK" are shown, and all other columns are hidden.
- When you change the condition, please modify `obj`.

#### Note:

- In this sample, the script can be run by the script editor, custom menu, a button and so on. But, if you want to automatically run this by a trigger, as a simple modification, please modify `myFunction` to `onEdit`. By this, the script is run by editing a cell. If you want to limit the edit cell, please add the condition to the above script.

#### References:

- [showRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showrowsrowindex,-numrows)
- [showColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.